# Show old generated key against same input

Tags: php, sql

This is the code i am working on

```
if(isset($_POST['generate'])) {
    $article_id = $_POST['generate']['id']; //escape string
    $domain = $_POST['generate']['domain']; //escape string
    $userid = $_POST['generate']['uid']; //escape string
    if(!$db->getRow("SELECT * FROM `".PREFIX."user_stats` WHERE `article_id` = ?i AND `domain` = ?s AND `userid` = ?i", $article_id, $domain, $userid)) {
        $key = randomIDGenerator();
        $http = "http://";
        $tracking = array(
            "userid" => $userid,
            "username" => $user->data->username,
            "article_id" => $article_id,
            "key" => $key,
            "domain" => $domain,
            "created" => $time
        );

        if(($db->query("INSERT INTO `".PREFIX."user_stats` SET ?u", $tracking)) && ($id = $db->insertId()) && ($db->query("UPDATE `".PREFIX."articles` SET `shared` = `shared` + ?i WHERE `article_id` = ?i", 1, $article_id))) {
            $tracking_url = $domain.$key;
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "Success", "url" => $http.$tracking_url));

        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "Error", "msj" => "Internal error. Please refresh the page and try again."));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "Error", "msj" => $domain.$key." Resharing."));
    }
}
```

It generate url for user and then show it, and if the url is already generated for same article then this is where the last "else" come

what I want is if even the url is generated before, it still show old generated url with resharing text

I tried  `$domain.$key." Resharing."` which shows the domain but not the key

and also I tried

`echo json_encode(array("status" => "Success", "url" => $http.$tracking_url));`

with no luck

I don't know how good i explained my problem please let me know if i need to explain more.

Comment: what response you receive ?

Comment: `what i want is if even the url is generated before, it still show old generated url with resharing text` could you explain this line?

Comment: @NN: Read the next line :)

Comment: where is this randomIDGenerator() function? Show this as well

Comment: @NN, All i want is the last "else" give the same output as 1st "if" or 1st "echo", but do not generate new url/key but show the old generated one again against the same domain & article.

Comment: @Naby: Check NN's answer.

Comment: @VishalParkash, its a function which generate random 6 digit string and then store it to "$key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$key is not set in your last else-branch. I assume the function getRow returns a result from the db and this result contains amongst others the key.

```
$result = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM `".PREF."...");
if(!$result) {
    $key = randomIDGenerator();
    $http = "http://";
    $tracking = array(
    //...
} else {
    // a guess how you could access the key from your result
    // depends on the return value of the function getRow
    $key = $result['key'];
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "Error", "msj" => $domain.$key." Resharing."));
```

Comment: After implementing your code i am getting error, i am sure i did not put the syntax right.

this is how it look like now (unable to post complete code in the comment, here is the screenshot) : http://prntscr.com/duoxol

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: the error message could be helpful and the line of code it affects. As I wrote in the code comment, i do not know, what your getRow-function returns. It could have been an array, but maybe it is not and this is the reason for your error. try `var_dump($result)` instead of `$key = $result['key'];` or post the code of getRow

Comment: Actually it do nothing, when i hit generate button it don't do anything or show any output or error, this mostly have happen when the code have any syntax error, i can be wrong. did you check the screenshot if its how you wanted ?

Comment: Same with var_dump($result).

Code of getRow ? it don't have the code, it Runs the query provided and puts the first row of data into an array then frees the result set.

Comment: add a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your file and post the your complete code by editing your question. The getRow function is not a default php function, so it must be somewhere in your appliction.

Comment: * Helper function to get single row right out of query and optional arguments

  `public function getRow()
    {
        $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
        if ($res = $this->rawQuery($query)) {
            $ret = $this->fetch($res);
            $this->free($res);

            return $this->ret($ret);
        }
        return FALSE;
    }`

found it.

Comment: found the mistake: `$db->getRow`

Comment: Still same :( and there is nothing with error reporting. I really very appreciate all the effort and time yo put into it.

Comment: we need the error. Try to fix your error reporting. Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Answer (score 1):

Please find the updated code
It was due to key was generated in if loop once the condition was jumped to else no key was found.

```
 if(isset($_POST['generate'])) {
 $article_id = $_POST['generate']['id']; //escape string
 $domain = $_POST['generate']['domain']; //escape string
 $userid = $_POST['generate']['uid']; //escape string
 $key = randomIDGenerator();

 if(!$db->getRow("SELECT * FROM `".PREFIX."user_stats` WHERE `article_id` = ?i AND `domain` = ?s AND `userid` = ?i", $article_id, $domain, $userid)) {

$http = "http://";
$tracking = array(
  "userid" => $userid,
  "username" => $user->data->username,
  "article_id" => $article_id,
  "key" => $key,
  "domain" => $domain,
  "created" => $time
);

if(($db->query("INSERT INTO `".PREFIX."user_stats` SET ?u", $tracking)) && ($id = $db->insertId()) && ($db->query("UPDATE `".PREFIX."articles` SET `shared` = `shared` + ?i WHERE `article_id` = ?i", 1, $article_id))) {
    $tracking_url = $domain.$key;
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "Success", "url" => $http.$tracking_url));

} else {
  echo json_encode(array("status" => "Error", "msj" => "Internal error. Please refresh the page and try again."));
}
  } else {

    echo json_encode(array("status" => "Error", "msj" => $domain.$key." Resharing."));
 }
}
```

Comment: Its showing the url where i wanted but generating new key each time i hit the generate what i need is it don't generate new link but show the old generated link against same domain and article.

the url is : domain/key